# Full .NET references .NET Standard class library: FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, entity-framework-core

I've just created 2 projects with Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.3):

1. class library (`netstandard2.0`)

   - +`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`, Version 2.2.4
   - +custom `Repository` class to hide `DbContext` class
2. WPF project (`v4.7.1`)

   - +reference to the class library above
   - +some code to use the `Repository`:

```cs
var r = new Repository(@"Server=(localdb)\MsSqlLocalDB; Database=EfCore2Wpf; Trusted_Connection=True;");
DataContext = r.GetItems(); // FileNotFoundException here.
```

Here's the complete exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'

That's right! There's no `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll` inside `\WpfApp\bin\Debug` folder.
**But why?**

(I have some legacy solutions with the same project types and they work. What's wrong here?)

---

For your information:

1) Including a single .NET Core package like `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` cause a Million `<Reference Include="..."><HintPath>..\packages\...dll</HintPath></Reference>` entries. **That's no option.**

2) As far as I remember I had to migrate my legacy WPF projects to pass indirect .NET Core references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference. But currently I don't need any NuGet package in my WPF project so there's no `package.config`. And without a `package.config` file **I cannot migrate**!

Comment: You are asking many things in one question, and at the same time putting constraint like no option for adding a .NET Core package in the project. Please be specific, and ask one problem at a time..

Comment: EF Core 2.x supports .NET Framework 4.7.2. Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/)?

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono Goal: Get it running without referencing packages I don't need.

Comment: @mm8 Uprading to .NET Framework 4.7.2 doesn't work.

Comment: @Marcel: Does it work if you manually copy the DLL into the output folder?

Comment: @mm8 Yes, it runs after I manually copy `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll`, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll`, `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll`, (+10 other dlls) AND setup a `<bindingRedirect />` for `System.ComponentModel.Annotations`

Comment: Do you have an option of using .NET Core 3.0 for your WPF project?

Comment: @awright18 You're right. This would theoretically work. But I can't upgrade any old WPF project in a reasonable amount of time. In fact this questions is aimed at upgrading all my legacy libraries FIRST and the clients LAST. Upgrading the WPF client now means upgrading everything at the same time. That's no option in real life. Besides that .NET Core has been supporting WPF since last month. I feel quite unfamiliarly with this subject.

Comment: Add this file manually, on specified path

Comment: Had the same problem with Nuget package System.Data.OleDB in .NET Standard project, referenced from a .NET Framework ASP.NET application. To my surprise I got it to work by installing the Nuget package System.Data.OleDB in the ASP.NET application too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug and not fixed because nobody cares: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/769172/a-full-net-project-is-not-in-packagereference-form.html

**Workaround:**

1. Add an arbitrary NuGet Package (e.g. `NLog`, `AutoMapper`, `MvvmLightLibs` or whatever).
2. Right-click on the new `packages.config` file → "*Migrate packages.config to PackageReference...*" (you might not need this step if "*PackageReference*" is your "*Default package management format*", check Tools → NuGet Package Manager)
   [image]
3. Works!

Or even faster: Add to your `*.csproj`

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Warning:** Use tool support like ReSharper's "*Optimize References...*" with caution! It would remove the unused reference. :-(

Comment: Visual Studio Feedback System: _I have detected that for the last 35 days, this issue didn't have much product team activity and a very small amount of new votes or comments. Based on this, its severity, and affected area, it’s my experience that this issue is very unlikely to be fixed._